# Play 2.x Get list of ebean entities

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I need to get a list of ebean entities in java.
Indeed i want the user select one entity in a html list to display entity's info.

How can i do get all entities in my database ?

Thanks.

Comment: I try somthing like that   `code    String sql = "SELECT table_name" +
                "  FROM information_schema.tables" +
                " WHERE table_schema='public'" +
                "   AND table_type='BASE TABLE';";
        SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);

        List<SqlRow> list = sqlQuery.findList();`

Comment: And it isn't working? That should give you the table names. You want to get the java classes names that map to those tables?

Comment: its work well but i need to map my table name equal to class name to work.

Comment: But in postgreSQL , table name are only minus so doesn't work...